# Unable to print the values of an instance of my model

Tags: class, object, constructor, kotlin

I know this is a very fundamental question but answer to this will solve many of my doubts.

```
val new_parent = ParentDetails(intent.extras.getString("name"), 
    intent.extras.getString("email"),
    intent.extras.getString("parent_relation"),
    intent.extras.getString("locationdata"))

println(new_parent.tostring())
```

The code above doesn't print the various fields and their values present in the class.

The `ParentDetails` is a model I have created with some fields that are initialized.  The `ParentDetails` model:

```
class ParentDetails {
    var parent_id: Int = 0
    var parent_name: String = ""
    var parent_email: String = ""
    var parent_relation: String = ""
    var parent_location: String=""

    constructor(parent_name: String, parent_email: String, parent_relation: String,parent_location:String) {
        this.parent_name = parent_name
        this.parent_email = parent_email
        this.parent_relation = parent_relation
        this.parent_location = parent_location
    }

    public fun getparentId(): Int {
        return parent_id
    }

    fun ParentDetailsprintme() {
        println(parent_name)
        println(parent_email)
        println(parent_relation)
        println(parent_location)
     }
}
```

In fact, it prints null and accessing individual fields, it prints empty string(the way it was initialized).

How do we explain this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand your problem is that calling `println(new_parent.tostring())` does not print what you would like to print in function `ParentDetailsprintme`.

First of all, you have a typo, the correct call would be `new_parent.toString()`.

Note that it could have been simplified as `println(new_parent)`.

It does not print that you defined in the `ParentDetailsprintme` method, as the method is not called.

What `println(new_parent.toString())` prints, is actually the hashcode of the object, as this is the default behaviour of every object.

To make it work call it like `println(new_parent.ParentDetailsprintme())` or override the `toString()` method for example as:

```
override fun toString() = "$parent_name $parent_email $parent_relation $parent_location"
```

then the following

```
val new_parent = ParentDetails("myName", "myEmail", "myParent_relation", "myLocationdata")
println(new_parent)
```

should print

```
myName myEmail myParent_relation myLocationdata
```

---

Kotlin's [`println`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.2.60/libraries/stdlib/jvm/src/kotlin/io/Console.kt#L140) function simply calls `System.out.println(message)` under the hood which will call `String.valueOf()` (e.g. [`String.valueOf(Object object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)) for objects, which will call the `toString()` method of the passed object).

```
/** Prints the given message and newline to the standard output stream. */
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun println(message: CharArray) {
    System.out.println(message)
}
```

---

*Update (*"Using data class method also works"*):*

If you make the class to be a data class:

```
data class ParentDetails(
        val parent_id: Int = 0,
        val parent_name: String = "",
        val parent_email: String = "",
        val parent_relation: String = "",
        val parent_location: String = ""
)
```

and then you execute

```
val new_parent = ParentDetails(0, "myName", "myEmail", "myParent_relation", "myLocationdata")
println(new_parent)
```

you will receive as result

```
ParentDetails(parent_id=0, parent_name=myName, parent_email=myEmail, parent_relation=myParent_relation, parent_location=myLocationdata)
```

This is because [data classes](http://ParentDetails(parent_id=0,%20parent_name=myName,%20parent_email=myEmail,%20parent_relation=myParent_relation,%20parent_location=myLocationdata)) override the `toString()` function:

> The compiler automatically derives the following members from all
>   properties declared in the primary constructor:
>
> - equals()/hashCode() pair;
> - **toString() of the form "User(name=John, age=42)";**

Comment: Why is the way I have written not working? Using data class method also works. But I'm looking for an explanation as to why the way I have written isn't working the way I thought it should.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check that you receive valid data from your `intent.extras`?

Also I suggest you use `data class` for your models.
It will look something like this:

```
data class ParentDetails(
    var parent_id: Int = 0,
    var parent_name: String = "",
    var parent_email: String = "",
    var parent_relation: String = "",
    var parent_location: String = ""
)
```

You will be able to use it like this :

```
val new_parent = ParentDetails(
        parent_name = intent.extras.getString("name"),
        parent_email = intent.extras.getString("email"),
        parent_relation = intent.extras.getString("parent_relation"),
        parent_location = intent.extras.getString("locationdata")
    )
    println(new_parent.tostring())
```

Comment: Thank you. This works but why is the way I have written not working? Moreover, the intent.extras return valid. I have checked.

Comment: @Eswar data class generates `toString()` fun for you (as well as a couple of other). I guess it was the main issue in your case. Check out [data class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, you have a typo. `toString` returns the hashcode of an object unless it's overridden to return something else. Look up the original implementation for more details.

By overriding the `toString` method, you change what it returns, and through that, what is printed when you `print(someClass)`. DVarga showed that in their answer.

[Data classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html) auto-generate a `toString` method containing the content of the class. So creating a data class is a shortcut to getting output containing the data.

The reason the method you had didn't work is because you didn't call it. if you call it instead of `toString`, you would get the data printed.

Also, `toString` is explicitly called when you print a class. You don't need to call `print(someInstance.toString())`, `print(someInstance)` is enough.

---

And while I'm writing an answer, you don't need to use secondary constructors in Kotlin. Primary constructors would shorten your code significantly, whether it's a data class or not. Also, you should look into naming conventions.